# GetGenericParameterConstraints of interface with self referenced constraint

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-4.0

I'm trying to fix this issue of NHibernate NH-3260 and stuck on overriding generic methods which have generic interface constraints which is reference base class.

For example I have following model:

```
public interface IMyGenericInterface<TId>
{
}

public class MyGenericClass<TId> : IMyGenericInterface<TId>
{
    public virtual TRequestedType As<TRequestedType>() 
        where TRequestedType : MyGenericClass<TId>
    {
        return this as TRequestedType;
    }

    public virtual TRequestedType AsInterface<TRequestedType>() 
        where TRequestedType : class, IMyGenericInterface<TId>
    {
        return this as TRequestedType;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to do following

```
[Test]
public void GenericTypeConstraint()
{
    var type = typeof (MyGenericClass<int>);
    var method = type.GetMethod("As");

    var genericArgument = method.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // TRequestedType : MyGenericClass<TId>
    var typeConstraint = genericArgument.GetGenericParameterConstraints()[0]; // MyGenericClass<TId>

    Assert.AreEqual(typeof(MyGenericClass<>), 
                    typeConstraint); // This works
}

[Test]
public void GenericInterfaceConstraint()
{
    var type = typeof (MyGenericClass<int>);
    var method = type.GetMethod("AsInterface");

    var genericArgument = method.GetGenericArguments()[0]; // TRequestedType : class, IMyGenericInterface<TId>
    var typeConstraint = genericArgument.GetGenericParameterConstraints()[0]; // IMyGenericInterface<TId>

    Assert.AreEqual(typeof (IMyGenericInterface<>), 
                    typeConstraint); // Fails with 

    /*
    Expected: <NHibernate.Test.DynamicProxyTests.GenericMethodsTests.IMyGenericInterface`1[TId]>
    But was:  <NHibernate.Test.DynamicProxyTests.GenericMethodsTests.IMyGenericInterface`1[TId]>
    */
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is that you supply `typeof (IMyGenericInterface<>)` as the expected value. This is the open generic (`IsGenericTypeDefinition = true`). However, `typeConstraint` is the closed generic (`IsGenericTypeDefinition = false`).

To make your test pass, change the assert to this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(typeof (IMyGenericInterface<>),
                typeConstraint.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
```

Comment: @hazzik: What exactly do you want me to look at?

Comment: That it works when the constraint is a generic class but not an interface

Comment: @hazzik: Interesting. The technical reason is that the `As` method seems to return an open generic (`IsGenericTypeDefinition = true`), while the `AsInterface` doesn't (`IsGenericTypeDefinition = false`). But why that is, I currently can't explain.

Comment: @hazzik: BTW: I hope you are aware of the fact that your methods can return `null`.